# DLL injection, c++ , dll doesn't have svchost rights why?

Tags: c++, dll-injection, access-rights

unfortunately I have a problem concerning injecting svchost. The code looks like that:

```
#include "Injection.h"
#pragma once 
#include <Windows.h>

DLLInjection::DLLInjection()
{

}
void DLLInjection::InjectDLLTosvchost(LPSTR dllPath)
{
        STARTUPINFO si = {};
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

        HMODULE k32 = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
        CreateProcess(NULL, "svchost.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
        HANDLE mem = VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, NULL, 260, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE , PAGE_READWRITE);
        WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, mem, dllPath, 260, NULL);
        QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)GetProcAddress(k32, "LoadLibraryA"), pi.hThread, (ULONG_PTR)mem);
        QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)GetProcAddress(k32, "ExitThread"), pi.hThread, 0);
        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

}
DLLInjection::~DLLInjection()
{

}
```

the dll which is executed looks pretty much like that:

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funkcje.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;
void Hello()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"poczatkowy messagebox", (LPCWSTR)L"Tytul messagebox", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    char bufor[512];
    sprintf(bufor, " -add -all -c \"c:\\Users\\Damian\\Desktop\\wwwtesthttpdev.crt\" -s -r LocalMachine root");
    wchar_t bufor2[200];
    mbstowcs(bufor2, bufor, strlen(bufor) + 1);
    LPWSTR ptr = bufor2;
    STARTUPINFO startInfo = { 0 };

    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = { 0 };

    BOOL bSucces = CreateProcess((LPWSTR)(L"c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1A\\Bin\\certmgr.exe"), ptr, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo);

    if (bSucces)
    {
        cout << "Process Started" << endl
            << "Process ID:  " << processInfo.dwProcessId << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error to start a process    " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"koncowy messagebox", (LPCWSTR)L"Tytul messagebox", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    cin.get();

}
```

and the dll is loading fine, because I do have the two messageboxes (one before executing the createProcess command and one after) but the problem is that I do not have rights to successfully make the certmgr.exe command (and it returns the message that certmgr was not successful. If I open the program with administrator rights everything works fine. But it shouldn't work like that. I am trying to get attached to the svchost process which should have administrator rights, but despite doing it I still do not have rights. Can anyone help me answering the question how I can make my program pass the administrator rights to the function that is executed in Dllmain.
Thank you in advance!!
[the error with certmgr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGTvz.png)

I have also tried with OpenProcess:

```
bool Process::InjectDll(char * dllName, unsigned int processID)
{
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, processID);
    if (pHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;
    void * address = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, NULL, strlen(dllName), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, address, (LPVOID)dllName, strlen(dllName), NULL))
        return false;
    HMODULE hK32 = GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");
    HANDLE tHandle = CreateRemoteThread(pHandle, NULL, 0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hK32, "LoadLibraryA"),
        address, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(tHandle, INFINITE);
    DWORD dllAddress;
    GetExitCodeThread(tHandle, &dllAddress);
    CloseHandle(tHandle);
    VirtualFreeEx(pHandle, address, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    tHandle = CreateRemoteThread(pHandle, NULL, 0,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hK32, "FreeLibrary"), (void*
        )&dllAddress, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(tHandle, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(tHandle);
    return true;
}
```

but it also doesn't work

Comment: Elevating user rights in programs is exactly what windows wants to avoid. What makes you think you should be able to do it ?

Comment: I am trying to get into the process trhat has the rights so expect that the additional code will also have them

Comment: Please add exact output of `cout << "Error to start a process    " << GetLastError() << endl;`

Comment: There is no error output because the process is created. The only thing is that certmgr cannot finish and add the cerrtificate. I've added the picture in the description :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `CreateProcess` You are running an additional instance of `svchost` using the default security descriptor (From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> If lpProcessAttributes is NULL or lpSecurityDescriptor is NULL, the process gets a default security descriptor

And it seems that these privileges are not sufficient to run `certmgr`.

---

Instead, if your injector used `OpenProcess` and injected into the already elevated `svchost`, you would be able to run `certmgr`.

Comment: So how could I improve it?

Comment: I have updated the description :) when it comes to the second solution (with openprocess, I have a problem with writing to memory in the line with WriteProcessMemory)

Comment: @Dandeiro1992, but of course. Your process doesn't have elevated privileges, so it cannot write to the elevated `svchost`. What you are trying to do is called "privilege escalation" (Execute an app with administrator privileges from an app that have no such privileges). The OS puts a lot of efforts to prevent these kind of attacks. If I would have known how to achieve that, I would probably have some extra cash right now. You could read about **past exploits** that managed to achieve that, but don't expect this kind of information on SO.